# Optimization for ever increasing key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem itself is quite simple:

- I have a large number of timestamp and value pairs
- The timestamps with a few exceptions (<1%) are ever increasing and unique
- I use the timestampt as clustered index

How can I enforce that the DB system try to insert the value to the end, and if it fails (does not go rightmost (large side) in the B-tree, that can be checked const time) only then do the binary search for the correct placement?

Target system: MSSQL 2016 or 2017

Comment: That's what a clustered index does. But why do you care how the internals work?

Comment: Locating a row in a B-tree index does not actually use a binary search; that would take too many disk reads. B-tree indexes optimize for minimal reads with multiple levels. What you're trying to optimize away here is locating the data page the row will ultimately end up in, which is *not* the bottleneck of the entire operation -- that would be actually *writing* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you want `timestampt` to be a clustered index or you do not.  There is no "half-way" clustered index.

So, if you want it clustered, then leave extra space on each page in case a new value gets inserted later.  You can control this by using `fill_factor` (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-2017)).  This allows a clustered index to (more) efficiently insert values that are not at the end.

If you don't want a clustered index on `timestampt`, then use an `identity` column to identify each row.  This will ensure that rows are only inserted at the "end" (i.e. last page) of the table, making inserts more efficient.  You can still have a regular index on `timestampt` for efficient access.

Actually, I prefer the second method.  I would be concerned about duplicates in `timestampt`, and I prefer having a clustered index that uniquely identifies each row.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to actually use `FILLFACTOR`, because 1) it doesn't do what most people think it does and 2) even what it does is typically not helpful/useful. This is certainly true if data is >99% sequential. You would need to rebuild the existing index before `FILLFACTOR` even does anything -- it does *not* leave empty space in pages as part of an insert and will *not* proactively keep an "almost sequential" set of values free from page splits (but with highly sequential values, the impact of those will be limited anyway).